# How to use SQL JDBC driver with Spark and Zepplin

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to read data form SQL server to process using Spark. I am using Zeppelin for writing my scala commands. I never worked on Java or Spark or Zeppelin, so I am having hard time figuring out the issues.

I installed spark on my machine and everything seem to be working as I can get to spark-shell successfully. I have installed Zeppelin via Docker and this also seem to be working as I can create a new notebook and run "sc" and can see the SparkContext type printed.

Now I want to read data from SQL Server. I am planning to use [azure-sqldb-spark connector](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark) but I am not sure how to use it. I am trying to add this as an interpreter to Zeppelin but not sure what are the required properties and how to use it.

This is what I did so far.

1. Downloaded the [jar](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark/releases/download/1.0.1/azure-sqldb-spark-1.0.1.jar) file from GitHub repo. (I am not able to run this on my machine as this is complaining that there is no manifest file)
2. Copied this jar file to the container running zeppelin
3. Tried to create an interpreter in Zeppelin

Here are the properties:

[image]

I am specifying the dependency on jar file like this.

[image]

I tried to play with the properties a bit but no luck. I am not even sure if this is the right way to do this.

I am trying to run the following query but running into suitable driver not found issue.

[image]

Comment: JDBC interpreter understands only sql syntax. Your code should bi run in spark interpreter.

Comment: yes, I have spark interpreter enabled for the notebook, if that is what you are referring to.